# Mysql last 30days but excluding records from 3days

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following schema for attendance table:

```
ID, roll_no, created_date
```

Everyday attendance get taken. An a record gets inserted for each rollno on daily basis.

Now,
I want a list of roll_no which are coming to school from past 30days but have stopped coming from past 3days. wondering what query will work for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
select roll_no
  from attendance
  where created_date > now() - interval 30 day          -- attended in last 30 days
  group by roll_no
    having max(created_date) < now() - interval 3 day;  -- last attended 3 days ago
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b53a7/1)